# Safe To Append to File When Looping?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, append, text-files

In one of my previous questions here I was educated about not modifying a list when looping, but to first make a copy of the original list and use that. Does the same apply when appending to a text file? Is there any dangers in appending to a text file while looping. Here is the code I created and want to use:

```
rule = ["rule 1", "rule 2", "rule 3"]

def rule_file(rule):
    with open('rules.txt', 'a') as f:
        for r in rule:
            f.write(r + "\n")

rule_file(rule)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were appending to a text file *while reading from that file*, you might have issues. Here, though, the thing you're modifying is unconnected to the list you're iterating over. It's fine. The problems only occur when you modify the same thing you iterate over.